# elementary OS 0.4 Loki, How To Edit Grub

Tags: grub

I am a new user of elementary OS, but I have messed around with various different Linux distros for s few years. My question is quite simple, I need to change the Grub menu to have a different OS (Windows 10, sorry) load first. What I mean is that right now elementary OS is the first OS on the Grub menu, but I need Windows 10 to be the first OS in the Grub menu.

I have tried to add the Grub customizer but I can not seem to do that in elementary, although it has worked in other distros in the past.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Rocky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a file /etc/default/grub
You may change a line there, saying

> `GRUB_DEFAULT=0`

Uncommenting and changing it to

> `GRUB_DEFAULT=SOME_NUMBER`

will change the default line in your grub screen to the "SOME_NUMBER+1".
So **if your windows 10 line is the 2nd then you need GRUB_DEFAULT=1**

To do this it is better to make the backup of the file, change the line and update grub. The commands are:

> `sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub_ORIGINAL_BACKUP`
>
> `sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/default/grub`

change the line and then

> `sudo update-grub`

The windows line will stay where it was, but will become default.

Comment: Thank you very much Evgenil, I performed those steps exactly the way you indicated and it "kind of" helped. The process did change the boot order somewhat, but now the Grub boot loader starts on the second line, which is advanced options for elementary. I really need the Grub boot loader to start on the third line, which is Windows 10.

Comment: So, the fact that windows 10 is the 3rd means that you need to use GRUB_DEFAULT=2.
Try and, please, tell if it worked, or not.

Comment: Glad to help!
Could you please mark the answer as accepted then?
And why didn't grub-customizer worked?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to get Grub Customizer installed.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt update
sudo apt install grub-customizer
```

Comment: I have tried that many times, even before I asked here. This is what I get;


rocky@rocky-All-Series:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
[sudo] password for rocky:             
sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found
rocky@rocky-All-Series:~$

Comment: where error is it returning when you try to install it via the PPA? It is possible, I've done it many times.

Comment: Yeah, I just don't know what is wrong with command, it has worked for me in Ubuntu and Debian, but it just does not work in elementary, as I have posted the results a few minutes ago. Oh well, the situation is corrected.

Comment: Ok I know what the issue is, or I think I do. In elementary you can't install from PPAs out of the box. You need to run this command to allow it:    sudo apt install software-properties-common python3-software-properties python-software-properties     ---this will come in handy in the future even if you have the grub issue resolved.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, that information just might come in handy in the future. Thanks again for helping me out.